# Как сделать регресивную нейронную сеть на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, нейронные-сети, keras, tensorflow

как можно реализовать регресивную нейронную сеть на Python?
Недавно начал изучать нейросети, и столкнулся с проблемой. Я сделал самую простую игру Змейка на Python. Как можно сделать нейросеть, которая будет управлять змейкой? Т.е давать ей координаты змейки, координаты яблока по иксу X, и получать направление движения змейки, например 0 - налево, 1 - направо. Соответственно также для Y координаты.

Comment: А что такое "РЕГРЕСИВНАЯ нейронная сеть ". Поясните этот термин так, как вы его понимаете?

Comment: Зачем для такой задачи вообще нейронная сеть?

Comment: @passant т.е. нейронная сеть которая обрабатывает не изображения, а числа.

Comment: @Xander для изучения мира нейросетей и практики их написания.

Comment: @Антон что значит "нейронная сеть которая обрабатывает не изображения, а числа"?

Comment: @Антон  - ВСЕ нейронные сети обрабатывают числа. Даже если вы думаете, что сеть обрабатывает изображение, на самом деле она обрабатывает оцифрованное изображение, т.е. изображение представлено длинной последовательностью чисел. Повторяю вопрос - что такое "РЕГРЕСИВНАЯ нейронная сеть". Если это ваше личное изобретение - поясните его. Если вы считаете, что это общепринятый термин - дайте ссылку на его определение. Вы же хотите, что бы ваш вопрос правильно поняли?

Comment: @passant извиняюсь запутался, регрессивная нейросеть - это сеть, которая предсказывает числа и т.д., т.к. есть сети которые классифицируют изображения и т.д.

Comment: Для изучения нейросетей всё-таки лучше для начала выбирать типовые задачи. Даже если вы очень много будете практиковаться в забивании гвоздей микроскопом, то это никак не продвинет вас в понимании этого инструмента.

Comment: @Xander увидел видео на YouTube, как нейросеть играет в змейку и решил повторить)

Comment: @Антон -  т.е. на Ютубе посмотрели видеолекцию о том, как сделать нейросеть играющую в змейку. Отлично. Решили повторить - ну так повторите.  Вот как там рассказывают - так и делайте.  Что-то непонятного в видеоролике? Так его повторить в непонятном месте можно.   А на этом форуме -  задайте конкретный вопрос о том, что совсем-совсем там  не понятно. Мы же не будем тут вам второй ролик снимать "как сделать нейросеть со змейкой"  или Python'у вас учить.

Comment: @passant так в том то и дело, что в этом видеоролике показывается только работа нейросети, а не то как ее сделать. Я хочу у вас узнать ссылку на статью хотя бы где рассказывается как подобное можно сделать.

Comment: @ Антон - не думаю,  что люди, которые серьезно в теме сохраняют ссылки на такие полубредовые примеры, к жизни отношения не имеющие. А искать  в Гуугл -  ну вам самому лень, это понятно. А нам-то ради чего?

Comment: @passant В Гугл я искал и ничего не нашел. А идея для меня не бредовая, т.к. я хочу сделать нейросеть которая будет обучаться в процессе игры и посмотреть до какого уровня игры она дойдет.

Comment: @Антон - ну, хотите -  делайте. Можете сюда еще и "reinforcement learning" прикрутить, что-бы совсем интересно было и хоть чуть-чуть в тему. Только если вы не умеете в Гуугле самостоятельно искать - будет вам не легко. Очень. Сразу предупреждаю. Удачи!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это называется нейросеть с подкреплением.Сперва то обычные черно белые картинки свои научится распозновать бы и там логические операции,потом к более сложному.Кодируете команды A-влево=0.01,В-вправо=0.02,C,D(вверх,вниз),сперва рандомно в цикле идут,потом успех 1(получение балов) и 0.Потом она должна генерировать команды,думаю архитектура типа 4 входа, 5 выходов(1 для успеха/нет).То есть по достижению минимальной ошибки,должна как то генерировать команды.Думаю так)

Comment: Можно ссылку на статью где примерно такое описывается?

Comment: @Антон гугл- 'хабр пример нейросети' и первые 9 ссылок можно читать(может и дальше, не смотрел).там гдето есть примеры на питоне с картинками. некоторые места там будут повторяться, но помогут понять.

Comment: @Интик уже нашел до вашего ответа, но спасибо. Можете подсказать какую лучше выбрать функцию активации?

Comment: логистическую. но линейный перцептрон наверное проще

Comment: Спасибо, выбрал сигмоиду